# Android onesignal NotificationReceivedHandler

Tags: android, notifications

I have implemented the code to recvice notifications,Howerver application is successfully sending notificarion. I want perform some task when notification recive on device.
Below is my manifestfile and java class:

**Java class**

```
public class PushIntentService extends Activity implements OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler {

    @Override
    public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "USer status is :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        JSONObject data = notification.payload.additionalData;
        String customKey;

        if (data != null) {
            customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "USer status is :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            if (customKey != null)
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "USer status is :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




   }
        }
```

**manifestfile:**

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".MediaPlaybackService" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Login_cls"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Signup_cls"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddFriends"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SendSongReq"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ViewSongRequest"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SongPlay"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AcceptActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Music_Cls"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".PushIntentService"></activity>

</application>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is your problem please describe

Comment: when notification is recvied i want to display Toast with some message.

Comment: Basically i want to perform some task when notification is recived.

Comment: ok,are you receiving  notification or not.

Comment: yes i am receiving notification

Comment: i want to perform some task when my application is running and device receive notitfication.

Comment: `if (data != null) {
            customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);` Please check if condition,you are compiling  only 1st line,,that why Toast not displaying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156160/discussion-between-gowthaman-m-and-mudasar).