# Updating of shared preferences in OneSignal NotificationReceivedHandler not Working

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

I have successfully Setup OneSignal SDk ver # [4.0.0, 4.99.99]

And is able to send notifications and inApp messages.

However I want to retrieve text data from Notifications and do some update my Preferences KeyValues. What

I have tried:

```
public class NotificationService implements OneSignal.OSRemoteNotificationReceivedHandler{
   
    private static final String TAG = "NotificationService";
    private final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   
    @Override
    public void remoteNotificationReceived(Context context, OSNotificationReceivedEvent osNotificationReceivedEvent){
        OSNotification notification = osNotificationReceivedEvent.getNotification();
        
        Log.e(TAG,"remoteNotificationReceived (Title): " + notification.getTitle());   // This works
        Log.e(TAG,"remoteNotificationReceived (Body): " + notification.getBody());   // This works

        if(notification.getTitle().equals("CheckUserDate")) {   // This doesn't work
            SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            Date now = new Date();
            String dateString = formatter.format(now);
            editor.putString("InstallDate", dateString);
            editor.commit();
        }

        osNotificationReceivedEvent.complete(notification);

    }
}
```

Because this is declared in a separate class so,

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run(){
            if(notification.getTitle().equals("CheckUserDate")) {
            SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            Date now = new Date();
            String dateString = formatter.format(now);
            editor.putString("InstallDate", dateString);
            editor.commit();
            }
        }
    });
```

Will also not works. Please do give some other suggestions to store some values like date etc for further use in app.

Same kind of problem here [Android onesignal NotificationReceivedHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619801/android-onesignal-notificationreceivedhandler) without answers